# from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold renaming and depreaction of cross_validation

Tags: python-3.7

i used in my code `from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold` and it was working without no issue .

now i got error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'`

i google it and i found that the package function is renamed to `model_selection` instead of `cross_validation` but i have to use `KFold` function `from  sklearn.cross_validation import KFold`.
the `sklearn` version i have is 0.20.1 with Python 3.7.1

using `KFold` which is a method already implemented in  `sklearn.cross_validation`

`from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold`

expected to run sucessfully as before but i got below error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'`

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by importing the supported package which is `from sklearn.model_selection import KFold`
then modifying KFold method with correct parameters as below

```
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
```